# Spring Data JPA Derived Query Method for column value equals to another column value on the same entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have gone through Spring Data JPA docs, but couldn't find anything about what I'm asking here:

Is there any way to compare values of two different columns of same entity with each other in **derived query method** for the below simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM User user WHERE user.firstName=user.lastName
```

Comment: Are you looking for a method with query value for `@Query `annotation or a predefined method like `findByFirstNameEqualsLastName`?

Comment: Not @Query but Query Methods as you also mentioned, and we called them Query mthod not predefined methods

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to add a repo method with the annotation? It seems a reasonable solution to me, but I would love to learn your reasoning.

Comment: Well I would say it's just a common approach which I'm following for whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **Spring Data JPA does not have that functionality** as of version **2.7.0**

You can [create a new issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/new) on the public [github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa) and if the developers find it suitable (higher demand for the issue is a plus), it might be implemented in the future.

For now, *possibly* the best option for you is to use `@Query` annotation.